# Better way to show duplicates in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science, data-visualization

```
dups_df = df.pivot_table(columns=['DstAddr'], aggfunc='size')
print (dups_df )
```

I am using this code block to show the duplicates but I would like to see the output in order(most used one) and maybe with a better visualization. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the duplicated method, as show above:

```
print(df[df.duplicated(subset='DstAddr')]
```

You can see the whole documentation at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

Other way is value_counts method, as show above too:

```
print(df.value_counts(subset='DstAddr', ascending=False))
```

Documentation at  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html

To vizualize this, I you can you value_counts and add a plot method.

```
df.value_counts(subset='DstAddr', ascending=False).plot()
```

Documentation at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df.DstAddr.value_counts()
```

and:

```
df.DstAddr.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `duplicated()` method.
This method returns a Boolean values for each row:

**Example**
Returns True for every row that is a duplicate, otherwise False:

```
print(df.duplicated())
```

or if want to remove all duplicates you can use drop_duplicates() method.

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)
```